# Input datatype error

Tags: python

I have a program which takes a string and converts it into list which looks like this -   `['CTTC', 'CGCT', 'TTTA', 'CATG']`. (its actually a lot longer than this). Now I need to find how many of these list elements have a `C or A or T or G` as its 1st letter. This needs to be taken from the terminal i.e. using the `input` function.

Now as far i know, in python 3.2 the datatype of input function is by default taken as a string (`str`) and not like an integer (`int`) (can be seen by using `isinstance`). However since I am using a college server, the python version is older (i think 2.7 or later but below 3.0). In this case, when I use the input function to ask the user to choose a letter-     `initial = input("Choose a letter:")`, and when I enter any letter (A,T,G,or C) it gives me an error `NameError: name 'C' is not defined`. When i checked the datatype using `isinstance`, i realized that the python version takes the datatype of input as an `int` . When i try to convert it into a string, it gives the same error. Is it the problem of the version or is it something i am doing wrong. My code is below.

```
import sys
#import random

file = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
string = ''
for line in file:
    if line.startswith(">"):
        pass
    else:
        string = string + line.strip()


w = input("Please enter window size:")
test = [string[i:i+w] for i in range (0,len(string),w)]
#seq = input("Please enter the number of sequences you wish to read:")
#first = random.sample((test), seq)
print test
l = input("Enter letter for which you wish to find the probability:")
lin = str(l)
print lin
```

Comment: `input` is Python 2 is an entirely different thing than in Python 3. Use `raw_input` instead.

Comment: I have used input in my program and that has worked without any issue. You can see that if you browse through the code

Comment: Nonetheless that is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `raw_input`, not `input`. In Python 2.x, `input` expects valid Python code, where as `raw_input` will convert the input to string. In Python 3.x `input` works the same as `raw_input`.

To solve your *actual* problem, which is counting the number of first letters, you can use either a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) or a [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). `Counter` is only available if your Python version is 2.7 and above. `defaultdict` was added in 2.5.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> i = ['CTTC','CGCT','TTTA','CATG','ABCD']
>>> c = Counter(x[0] for x in i)
>>> c['C']
3
```

Here is the `defaultdict` approach:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for x in i:
...    d[x[0]] += 1
...
>>> d['C']
3
```